# NavigationDrawer background image loads in KitKat but not in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have implemented NavigationDrawer in one of my apps. when i test it on AndroidOne (running KitKat). it loads the background image perfectly well but when i try to run the same code in Nexus 5 (Lollipop). it doesn't load the background image.

here's my header.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="178dp"
android:background="@drawable/background_poly"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:text="@string/my_name"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:text="@string/my_email"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"

        />
</LinearLayout>

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile_pic"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/circleView"
    />
```

**EDIT:**

In logcat i see the following:

```
6572-6600/com.keshan.mytestapp E/﹕ appName=com.keshan.mytestapp, acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger    
6572-6600/com.keshan.mytestapp E/﹕ 0
```

Comment: Reducing the size of the background image helped to solve the problem but still i am curious about it because compared to AndroidOne device Nexus 5 has a better memory, processing power and everything + Android L still that large image loaded well in the low end device but not the high end device. any ideas?

Comment: try with 9 patch images